# angular rxjs correct use of share/share reply

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have these streams in a service class

```
public get posts$() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Post[]>(`${environment.PostsUrl}`).pipe(
      shareReplay(),
      catchError((err) => this.handleError(err))
    );
  }

  public get postsWithAddedPost$() {
    return merge(this.posts$, this.postInsertedAction$).pipe(
      scan((acc: any, value) => [value, ...acc])
    );
  }
```

and i have these properties in a component class

```
public get postsMine$() {
    return this.postsMineData$;
  }

  public get postsOther$() {
    return this.postsOtherData$;
  }

  private postsMineData$ = combineLatest([
    this.postService.postsWithAddedPost$,
    this.selectedTabAction$,
    this.authService.loggedInUser,
  ]).pipe(
    filter<[Post[], number, User]>(([posts, selectedTab, user]) => {
      return selectedTab == 0;
    }),
    map(([posts, selectedTab, user]) => {
      posts = posts.filter((post: Post) => this.filterPostsByMe(post));
      if (this.cachedPost != null) {
        posts.unshift(this.cachedPost);
      }
      posts.map(p => (p.userName = user.name));
      return posts;
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      this.errorMessage = err;
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );

  private postsOtherData$ = combineLatest([
    this.postService.posts$,
    this.selectedTabAction$,
    this.authService.users$,
  ]).pipe(
    filter<[Post[], number, User[]]>(([posts, selectedTab]) => {
      return selectedTab == 1;
    }),
    map(([posts, selectedTab, users]) => {
      posts = posts.filter((post: Post) => this.filterPostsByOther(post));
      posts.map((p) => (p.userName = users.find((u) => u.id == p.userId)?.name));
      return posts;
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      this.errorMessage = err;
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
```

and i call these methods in html file

```
 <mat-tab-group
    id="tabGroup"
    (selectedTabChange)="onSelectedTabChange($event)"
  >
    <mat-tab label="My Posts">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        <app-post-items [posts$]="postsMine$"></app-post-items>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Other Posts">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        <app-post-items [posts$]="postsOther$"></app-post-items>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

problem :

on page load , first tab calls Post$ data but when  a user clicks on another tab there is again a http call for post$ data even it has been setup for sharereply()

could you suggest what is the mistake and how can be corrected

expected :

the page should get post$ data only once for first tab when page loads and when a user clicks another tab , that tab should pick the post$ data from cache(sharereply)

Comment: is there a difference in behavior if you define `posts$` like this: `public posts$ = this.httpClient.get(...)` instead of using a getter?

Comment: @BizzyBob if i dont use public getter , i can not spyon the post$ for unit testing.. 
i.e if i want to mock the value which come from post$ , the variable property is not accessible on spyonProperty or spyon
do you how can i mock it without using public getter

Comment: i have something like this in my post list component.spec.ts file for a unit test
spyOnProperty(postService, 'posts$').and.returnValue(() =>
        of(allPosts)
      );

Comment: If you define `posts$` as `public`, I think you should be able to access it in your test.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Like @BizzyBob has pointed out, instead of applying shareReplay on the httpClient observable, do this

In TS

```
this.posts$ = this.postService.posts$.pipe(shareReplay())
```

and use the posts$ observable in your code.

In this case, httpClient observable is only created once. Currently, with each invocation, a new observable is being created. So shareReplay won't work as you have intended.

Comment: i can not cache post$ in the component class since post$ is being used by postsWithAddedPost$ in post.service.ts